# Is it possible to programmatically output expressions in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I think an example will make more sense. For example, Tokio has a Select! macro where we can pass in expressions such as

```
let result = tokio::select! {
   Some(x) = call_async_func(_param_1) => x,
   else => { break } 
};
```

I have a use case where I need to call the `call_async_func()` method several times with different arguments. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
// what I want, in pseudo-rust
let parameter_list = get_parameter_list();
let result = tokio::select! {
   get_parameter_list.into_iter().map(|parameter| Some(x) = call_async_func(parameter) => x)
}
```

The benefit is that I don't have to tack on new expressions in the macro every time I decide to add a new parameter but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Look at [`futures::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/future/fn.select_all.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The body of a macro needs to have a structure matching what the macro defines, so the `Some(x) = async_fn() => expr` part needs to appear literally.

`tokio::select!` is only suitable for cases where you have a statically known number of asynchronous expressions to wait on. In cases where you have e.g. a list of them, you need something that takes a list of futures, e.g. [`futures::future::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) which waits for any of the futures to be ready. You can then check which one was ready in the result.